# Count iterations of an object array property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a lottery system to practice javascript and react.

I am having a hard time creating a function that will check my betObject array for the most common bet combination and list each bet featuring this combination(to make a sum of the bet amounts later).

Bets come in two types : pair and shuffle. Pair bets have a combination of 2 numbers while shuffle bets have a combination of 3 to 6 numbers. Result of the draw is a 2 number combination.

I have tried using filter, map and equations to make this work, I am trying to make use of a For loop but I can't see how to use it to help with my problem.I have also tried pasing the bet.combination to an Int or a String without success.

the betObject array is structured as follows :
[image: Bet Object Array log(int are purple, string are green)]

Here is my function so far :

```
const betsWatchList = () => {
    // Create watchlist array to store common bets array
    let watchlist = [];
    // loop through watchlist 
    for(let j = 0; j < watchlist.length; j++){
        //map through betList
        betList.map((bet, i) => {
            // if betlist combination matches watchlist
            if (watchlist[j].combination == bet.combination){
                // create new watchobject based on original
                let watchObject = {
                    combination : bet.combination,
                    total : watchlist[j].combination + bet.betTotal,
                    count : watchlist[j].count++
                }
                //replace original by updated
                watchlist.splice(j, watchObject);
            }else{
                //create new watchobject
                let watchObject = {
                    combination : bet.combination,
                    total : bet.betTotal,
                    count: 1
                }
                //push new watchobject
                watchlist.push(watchObject)
            }
        })
    } 
};
```

How would you approach this problem ? What should I change about my approach to find the solution faster ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Don't use `==` to test whether two arrays contain identical *values*

Try replacing

```
 if (watchlist[j].combination == bet.combination)
```

with

```
  if (JSON.stringify(watchlist[j].combination) == JSON.stringify(bet.combination))
```

#### Instead of `.splice`, why not just write to the array element?

The code has a missing `1,`. It should read `.splice(j, 1, watchObject)`. However, it is all unnecessarily complicated, and doesn't actually need a `.splice` as we are not changing the number of elements.

Replace

```
watchlist.splice(j, watchObject);
```

with

```
watchlist[j]= watchObject;
```

#### There was no reason to use `.map`

`.map` makes the programmer expect the code loop to return a result, when we could have used `.forEach` which makes it clear that it will not.

#### The loops are in reverse order

You need the *outer* loop to be over the bets. For each bet, you want the *inner* loop to examine each item in the watchList.

#### Just for simplicity, I have used `.forEach`

This avoids having to create and increment an iterator `i`.

```js
function betsWatchList(betList) {
  const watchList = [];
  betList.forEach(bet => {
    let found = false;

    // If already exists in watchList: update
    watchList.forEach((watchItem, j) => {
      if (JSON.stringify(watchItem.combination) === JSON.stringify(bet.combination)) {
        watchItem.total += bet.betTotal
        watchItem.count += 1
        found = true
      }
    });


    // If doesn't exist in watchList, append new watchList entry
    if (!found) {
      watchList.push({
        combination: bet.combination,
        total: bet.betTotal,
        count: 1
      });
    }

  })

  return watchList
}


const betList = [{
  combination: [1, 2, 3],
  betTotal: 10
}, {
  combination: [1, 2, 3],
  betTotal: 20
}, {
  combination: [1, 2, 4],
  betTotal: 10
}]

console.log(betsWatchList(betList))
```